# What siddur do Open Orthodox people use?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, prayer-book, orthodox

Do followers of [Avraham Weiss’s Open Orthodoxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avi_Weiss#Open_Orthodoxy) have their own siddur or use someone else’s? I’d be curious about any ways their liturgy might differ from the mainstream.

Comment: A Chovovei rabbi I know uses Koren.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://jewishbook.ca/images/siddur-tegilat-inside0003.jpg) to a "Open Orthodox Siddur"

Comment: @GershonGold *groan*

Comment: @GershonGold although strangely out of order

Comment: @wfb In Soviet Russia... I can't think of a good one.

Comment: @wfb - It's not out of order that is the order for the brachos according to the Chabad nusach.

Comment: @ezra what are you responding to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the people who daven at the Hillel Minyan at Northwestern University (where I davened in college) associate with the Open Orthodox movement. Most of them daven with the [Koren Sacks siddur](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/products/siddur/siddur/9789653010673). Some others use the Artscroll Siddur edition that includes the prayers for Israel, TzaHa"L, the United States, etc.

Since they use mainstream siddurim, their liturgy does not really differ from the mainstream. Most of the difference between them and more mainstream Orthodox Jews is difference in interpretation in hashkafa/halacha (depending on who you ask).

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering whether there would be any changes having to do with gender roles that would necessitate changes to the liturgy, but I guess it hasn't come to that yet.

Comment: @ablaze one thing that I have noticed is that during birkot hashachar, the person leading davening often says the bracha shelo asani isha quietly rather than out loud.

Comment: That's precisely the part I was wondering about. This whole inquiry started yesterday when I found some ostensibly Orthodox positions veering towards the kinds of liturgical changes the Conservative movement has made, especially in that spot. But actually rewording brachot is surely on the other side of a line.

Comment: I suspect that at this point at least, those who want to make Open Orthodox suggested changes (such as omitting the bracha sh'lo asani isha, the mention of niddah in long Tachanun, etc) are knowledgeable enough to make them "on the fly".  Those who don't know enough to skip these passages might not care enough about them.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is not yet a dedicated Open "orthodox" siddur, those associated with this label tend to have a problem with the beracha of "shelo asani ishah." This was the topic of [volume 2 of the Yeshivat Maharat journal, Keren](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5348363de4b0531dce75bc53/t/53d26414e4b07304e9025a47/1406297108086/Keren+2+Online.pdf), and it has also been discussed repeatedly on Morethodoxy, which is apparently another name for the movement. See, e.g., [here](http://morethodoxy.org/2009/06/29/goodbye-shelo-asani-god-didnt-make-me-a-hello-sheasani-yisrael-god-made-me-a-yisrael-rabbi-asher-lopatin/), [here](http://morethodoxy.org/2011/08/08/a-clamer-and-fuller-articulation-r-yosef-kanefsky/), [here](http://morethodoxy.org/2011/08/25/breaking-news-soloveichik-agrees-with-lopatin-accr/), and [here](http://morethodoxy.org/2011/08/11/a-story-from-the-front-lines-special-guest-post-by-rachel-kohl-finegold-education-and-ritual-director-anshe-sholom/).

See also: [the open siddur project](http://opensiddur.org/), [Seder Oneg Shabbos](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/the-torch/an-orthodox-friendly-egalitarian-bencher-something-old-something-very-new/), [The Lieberman Open Orthodox Haggadah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652298050).

Comment: "Morethodoxy, which is apparently another name for the movement." ??? Why would you say that? There was a blog with that name. Is _Hirhurim_ another name for regular Orthodoxy?

Comment: @DoubleAA hirhurim doesn't sound at all like another form of orthodoxy

Comment: Re Keren II: R Farber's piece is a good historical survey of the blessings; R Klapper's is more deeply thought provoking, clearly explicating and organizing the issues at play. Most of the other pieces are either anecdotal, exaggerated, or abused as fora to bemoan other issues.

Comment: On the "morethodoxy" website they have a tab to "optional morethodoxy sites." The tab takes you to a few links to open orthodoxy websites. As they have presented it, it seems like they themselves are calling their movement morethodoxy